# AWK, Move $Line2 after $Line1 through passing line numbers

Tags: regex, awk

Good day,

I was wondering how to move a line after other. Both of the same file.

1. Passing the two number lines `-v var1="$Line1" -v var2="$Line2"`.
2. Move `$Line2` after `$Line1`, where always `$Line1 < $Line2`.

**Expected input**

```
Line1=2 
Line2=5

NR  $0
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
```

**Expected output**

```
NR  $0
1   a
2   b
5   e
3   c
4   d
6   f
```

Thank in advance for any clue

Comment: And now, is it clearer?

Comment: @Alejandro, does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Line1 comes before Line2, this should work:

```
Line1=2
Line2=5
awk -v var1="$Line1" -v var2="$Line2" \
'{ if ((NR <= var1) || (NR > var2)) { print $0; }
   else if (NR == var2) { print $0 buffer; }
   else { buffer=(buffer "\n" $0); }
 }' inputfile
```

All lines before the insertion point or after the extraction point are printed normally. When the extraction point is reached, that line and everything accumulated in the buffer is printed. Between the insertion point and extraction point, lines are added to the buffer instead of being printed out immediately.

Comment: Yes, Finally I could test your code. And, yes!!! Your proposal works smoothly :D Thank so much for helping me out and have a good rest of weekend ( :